# CGPoint: Cannot call value of non-function type `[Float]`

Tags: swift, xcode, graphics, cgpoint

I am developing an app, which should draw points when is touch, in the location of touch and when I have got 2 or more points, it should connect these points and fill up the new object.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if(draw == true){

        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: view)

            pointsX.append(Float(location.x))
            pointsY.append(Float(location.y))

            let touchIndicator = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: location.x - 10, y: location.y - 10, width: 20, height: 20))
            touchIndicator.alpha = 0.8
            touchIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            touchIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            self.view.addSubview(touchIndicator)
            touchIndicators.append(touchIndicator)
        }

    }
}
```

Everytime i save the x and y coordinates in float type into array pointX and pointsY. But when i need to draw a line between 2 points, it tells me an error Cannot call value of non-function type `[Float]`.

```
let squarePath = UIBezierPath()

    squarePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: pointsX(0), y: pointsY(0)))

    squarePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 100))
    squarePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200))



    squarePath.close()

    let square = CAShapeLayer()
    square.path = squarePath.cgPath
    square.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(square)
```

Is there any other solution, where can I save my CGPoints?

If I can ask for a code, that will be easier for me, I am not good in english, thank you.

Comment: I see you fixed one error - brackets, not parenthesis - now check out what type `CGPoints` use: `CGFloat`. Cast your `Floats` as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift uses square brackets to index arrays, and you are using parentheses.

```
squarePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: pointsX[0], y: pointsY[0]))
```

Comment: Oh, what a shame, really bad mistake, thank you.
But another problem is, that CGPoint does not support Float, I have to change to Double or Int.

Answer (score 0):

Here i created a function which allows you convert CGPoint To double

```
 func convertCgPointToDoule(location: CGPoint) -> Double {
        let position = sprite.position.y
        return return position - location.y

    }
```